# javascript function to prevent user from changing the value of a specific column

Tags: javascript

Hope you're doing well
I'm new to JavaScript and I need your help to complete the code below.
I've written a JS code as you can see below :

```
$("#input_KindCode").change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    RunSql("Select DateKey From ProjectExecution.Contractinfo WHERE PlanCode = " + $("#input_PlanCode").val() + " AND ProjectCode = '" + $("#input_ProjectCode").val() + "' AND  ContractCode = '" + $("#input_ContractCode").val() + "' AND KindCode = 1 ", function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $("#input_DateKey").val(data[0].DateKey);
            /////// THIS PART///////
        } else {
            $("#input_DateKey").val('');
            EnableCol("DateKey");
        }
    });
}
else {
    $("#input_DateKey")[0].value = '';
    EnableCol("DateKey");
};});
```

In the 'RunSql' part of the code , I'm checking whether the 'datekey' column has value if true the value will show up in the field otherwise the user must enter the value for the column.

The problem is I want to add something to the code . I want to show the value if it exists AND I want to disable the column so that the user can not change the value . I can not use the function 'disable column' cause it does not work in my case are there any other functions ??

so I want a function to prevent user from changing the value of the column if it is being shown on the field. the function must be written in the 'This part' part of the code
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is the function `EnableCol` defined? Could you include the essential part of the HTML also?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, but I thought someone should note that this code suggests end users will be able to run arbitrary SQL, meaning they can do whatever they want with your database. If this is for a public website, there should probably be a safer API between the frontend and the database.

Comment: Thanks . I have a data entry form on my application and a sql - server table which is the base and this is the Java script above on that form .if the user see the value on the 'datekey' column / field , he should not be able to change the value . I need that ! thanks

Comment: Dear @Nicholas . The field is a date field and user can not type anything . He should choose from the dates that are shown to him . so it's ok

Comment: it's odd that you have to **specifically** enable it, but it's not disabled if you don't ... seems like `EnableCol` does nothing - as to how to disable it ... that really depends on what sort of *control* you have there - which you haven't shown at all ... `I can not use the function 'disable column'` - well of course not, because that is a function that exsists only as a vague concept in your question

Comment: @Pantea Tourang, if you trust your users then you are right, but a user could always open the console and type `RunSql("drop table ProjectExecution.Contractinfo")`. I'm not sure what context this will be used in, so maybe your users will be trustworthy, but I thought mention it just in case.

Comment: $("#input_DateKey").val(data[0].DateKey) this part shows that the column has value exactly here i need to prevent user from changing the value .if I use disablecol function the problem is that the record wont be inserted to the table cause the value NULL passes for the datekey column !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this input field using jquery. To perform this you need to add one line.

**Code:**

```
if (data.length > 0) {
            $("#input_DateKey").val(data[0].DateKey);
            $("#input_DateKey").prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $("#input_DateKey").val('');
            $("#input_DateKey").prop('disabled',false);
            EnableCol("DateKey");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is the record won't be inserted cause it passes null for the column you have disabled !!! and the column is not Nullable !!

Comment: No, it won't pass null record even though it is disabled. You can fetch its value by $("#input_DateKey").val()